# Merging GSuite Accounts

Tags: google-workspace-for-business

I have about 10 clients that I manage gsuite accounts for. In each of these accounts I have an admin@domain.com account that I use to manage the domain. I was thinking about it today and that means I'm paying $720 a year for accounts I do not use other than to manage their users. I would much rather save that money.

Is is possible to merge all of these accounts in to one main account with each account being its own sub organizational unit. From what I can tell, they wouldn't be able to see each other nor would they have access to files and etc. The only thing they couldnt have is a custom logo in their gmail.

Can this be done? Should it be done? How could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to merge account from different G Suite organizations / main domains but you could manage your clients G Suite organizations / main domains by using a G Suite Partner account. To get this account you should fill an application forma and be accepted by Google. For further details see https://cloud.google.com/partners/become-a-partner/